# i setted footer height 0.0 still showing in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why its taking footer view?

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return 16;
    return 16.0;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    return view;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    return view;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the height to 0.01, not 0.0.